# How to move my files stored under my personal computer to my Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My question may sound funny to some of you since I am new to Terminal/Linux/Amazon AWS.
But how can I move (copy) the file that is stored under my personal computer to my Amazon EC2 instance?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scp`.

```
 scp -i privateKey.pem -r ./localDir ec2-user@ip:~
```

To copy from ec2, reverse the command

```
scp -i privateKey.pem -r ec2-user@ip:~/remote-dir ./localDir
```

Please ec2-user with Ubuntu if you are using Ubuntu. This will copy to the home folder of the instance

Note: Please note your private key file should not have too open permissions.

```
chmod 400 /path/to/privateKeyFile.pem
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, should I replace the 'ip' at the end with my own AWS IP ?

Comment: yes. its the public ip address of your ec2. dont forget to allow your home ip address in the security group of the instance.

Comment: please include keyfile with `-i` option. i forgot it. also makesure the file permissions are set to 400.

Comment: Could you edit your answer? When I do ```chmod 400 ./h56cho5.pem```, I get ```chmod: cannot access ‘./h56cho5.pem’: No such file or directory```, and

Comment: when I do ```chmod 400 ./h56cho5.pem -i```, I get  ```chmod: invalid option -- 'i'```

Comment: looks like the file is not in the current directory. `./` means current directory

Comment: Hello, should I log out of the my EC2 instance to do chmod 400 command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205706/discussion-between-arun-k-and-chico0913).

Answer (score 1):

Move is different to copy. I'll assume you mean copy. The simplest way to copy files from your local machine to a running EC2 instance is to `scp` them. That requires you to be able to SSH to the EC2 instance. Something like this:

```
scp -i mykey.pem myfile.png ec2-user@ec2-01-02-03-04.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~
```

This assumes you're using Amazon Linux on which the default user is `ec2-user`. Change this as appropriate, for example to `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to help out windows users:

If you are on a windows machine and you want to move files from a windows machine to a Linux EC2, then open command prompt in windows and execute the command as shown in the following format:

```
scp -i <path-to-key-pair-file> <path-to-file-in-local-machine> <remote-username>@<remote-host>:<path-to-folder-in-remote-machine>
```

Example:

```
C:\My_User\Projects>scp -i C:/My_User/Projects/developers_key_pair.pem C:/My_User/Projects/customer-service/target/customer-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user
```

PS: To perform this file transfer, you must initiate this operation from a local terminal, not from the EC2 terminal. In other words, you don't have to be connected to the EC2 instance via SSH to perform this transfer.